# Linear (in)dependence of the $\cos(nx)$ family

Tags: linear-algebra

> Let for all $n$ $\in$ $\Bbb N$, $f_n$ be a function in the vector Space *f*: $\Bbb R$ $\to$ $\Bbb R$. Let $f$ be defined as follows:
>   $$ f:\Bbb R \to \Bbb R $$
>   $$f_n(x) = \cos(nx)$$
>   Is the family $(f_n)_{n\in\Bbb N}$ linearly independent?

My guess is that indeed
$$ \lambda_1\cos(x) + \lambda_2 \cos(2x) +...+\lambda_n \cos(nx)=0 \iff \lambda_1=...=\lambda_n=0 $$
I know that setting $x = \pi$ , $\lambda_1 = \lambda_2$ , $\lambda 3 =...=\lambda_n=0$ leaves 
$$\lambda_1 -\lambda_2=0 $$
but that only shows that $f(\pi)$ is linearly dependent. I just cannot imagine, for instance, $\lambda_1 \cos(x)$ and $\lambda_2 \cos (2x)$ as being equal, since $\cos(x)$ and $\cos(2x)$ have very different outputs, and multiplying by scalars only "stretches" them which makes them differ even more. It is somehow geometrically clear but I cannot come up with a proof.

Comment: Taylor expand all of the terms to order $n$, show that no choice of the $\lambda_i$ can cancel all $n+1$ terms.

Comment: Equivalently, sample the linear combination at $n+1$ points, for example equally spaced in $[0, 2\pi)$, and show that at least one of the combinations must be non-zero for some $\lambda_i$ non-zero.

Comment: Using induction may also help

Answer (score 5):

Start from
$$
\lambda_1\cos(x) + \lambda_2 \cos(2x) +...+\lambda_n \cos(nx)=0.\tag{1}
$$
Evaluate at $x=0$ to get
$$
\lambda_1+\lambda_2+\dots+\lambda_n=0.
$$
Derivate the equation (1) twice an set $x=0$ to get
$$
\lambda_1+2^2\lambda_2+\dots+n^2\lambda_n=0.
$$
Keep repeating until you get a homogeneous system of $n$ linear equations with $n$ unknowns, and show that it has a unique solution.

Answer (score 2):

With the change of variable $t=\cos x$, you get the Chebyshev polynomials of the first kind, which are linearly independent as they are of different degrees.

Answer (score 0):

Since all these functions are eigenfunctions of the second derivative operator, for distinct eigenvalues $-n^2$ for $n\in\Bbb N$, they are linearly independent. For a concrete proof, one can prove any nontrivial linear combination to be nonzero by induction on the number of nonzero terms in the relation. This is obvious for a single term (as none of the functions is zero). If a linear combination with $k>1$ nonzero terms were zero, take a nonzero term involving the function $x\mapsto\cos(nx)$, and apply the linear operator $f\mapsto{f}+n^2f''$ to kill only that the term, leaving a linear combination with $k-1$ nonzero terms that is zero, but this can be assumed to not exist due to the induction hypothesis.